# AppleScript and Mail: Weird selection behaviour?

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email, script, bug

**I) Intro**

In AppleScript, when - for example - I do

```
tell application "Mail"

    set mselection to selection as list

    tell application "System Events"
        tell application "Mail"
            activate
        end tell
        keystroke "a" using {command down}
    end tell

   set selected messages of first message viewer to mselection

end tell
```

I expect that my selection in Mail (e.g. two highlighted messages right next to each other) is "saved" to the variable named `mselection` first and and "removed" as all messages are selected by AppleScript, so all messages are highlighted. This happens as intended.

**II) Problem and Question, Call for confirmation by others, Specs**

In a next step I expect AppleScript to highlight the previous selected messages again, since I'm "loading" my "saved" selection via said variable. This does not happen as expected: In my Mail application my selection reappears, yes, **but is shifted one down**...

**>>> Why is that? And how to solve this?**

*I would also be happy for confirmation by the community that it is not just me... To test this copy-paste this script into AppleScript, open Apple Mail and select one or more messages in your inbox, then switch to AppleScript, start the script and enjoy your very own magic show. Add some delays into those gaps for more suspense...*

*BTW my app/system versions: OS X 10.11.6, AppleScript 2.8.1, Apple Mail 9.3.*

The variable is - of course - not changed during this script. A quick `return` of the variable at the end of the script can confirm that. So I guess it's Apple Mail which wants to select the next message...

**III) My workaround, i.e. not a solution**

I've written a rather *lengthy and relatively slow script* to get rid of this problem. It is probably not quite mature and could maybe be shorter (?), also it doesn't take certain scenarios into account (like the switching of inboxes). *Nevertheless it seems to do the job.* But a **solution** - instead of a workaround that cycles through the messages to select the ones above the actual selection, only to be shifted down once the alternative selection is applied! - **would be better**, indeed... *So maybe I'm just not seeing it, and there is a real solution after all!*

```
tell application "Mail"
    -- set up backup routine if failing: get first unread message in "foremost" inbox
    set mbu to message 1 of inbox whose read status = true
    -- Doesn't work if the fist read message is e.g. in the trash. Then nothing is selected...?!
    set fail to 0

    try
        --"log" the selected messages to later return to them
        set msel to selection as list
        set lc to (count of msel)
        set m1 to item 1 of msel

        set mbox to m1's mailbox
        set mid to m1's id

        set mc to count of messages in mbox

        -- cycle (below...) through messages above selection to determine their position = workaround of the weird selecting of the message below the one indicated by id...?!
        set mab to 0
        set mnr to 0

    on error
        --goto backup routine if no message is selected or another problem occured and end script
        set fail to 1
    end try

    -- do the following for all selected messages
    repeat with i from 1 to lc
        if fail is 1 then
            exit repeat
        end if
        -- replace selected message with the one above it = workaround for weird selecting shift...
        repeat (lc - mnr) times
            --increase the message number for the testing of the next selected message
            set mnr to mnr + 1
            set tester to message mnr of mbox
            if tester's id > mid then
                --save message and test next one
                set mab to tester
            else if tester's id = mid then
                -- message found, save the one above. Problem: If it is the first one, because none is above - goto workaround via mbu. At this point, multiple selections including the first message will be replaced by the first (read) one alone, because the weird selection problem is resolved by a keystroke which undoes multiple selections - for now...!
                if mnr = 1 then
                    set fail to 1
                    exit repeat
                end if
                --when the selected message is found, replace the selected message above it.
                set item i of msel to tester
                exit repeat
            else
                -- something went wrong (maybe a selected message was deleted?!), goto mbu = select first read.
                set fail to 1
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell

-- do stuff here, e.g.:
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Mail"
        activate
    end tell
    keystroke "a" using {command down}
end tell

-- revert selection

tell application "Mail"
    if fail is 1 then
        -- select earlier defined first read message; weirdly this selects the one below it, again...
        set selected messages of first message viewer to mbu

        -- so, we go one up via key stroke
        tell application "System Events"
            tell application "Mail"
                activate
            end tell
            key code 126
        end tell
    end if

    set selected messages of first message viewer to msel
end tell
```